# Adjust an sweep-alike function to a tidyverse command

Tags: r, matrix, tidyverse

I have the following example code:

```
# Create a vector and a matrix with the same number of columns
vector <- c(2, 3, 4)
matrix <- matrix(c(1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9), ncol = 3)

# Perform column-wise scalar multiplication
result <- matrix * rep(vector, each = nrow(matrix))

# Print the result
cat("Column-wise scalar multiplied matrix:\n", result)
```

I tried to adjust this function to a recipe using the tidyverse package, to no success. Could anyone help me here, please?

I tried using step_mutate() and rewrite the function inside using all_predictors(), and it did no multiplication. The data frame stayed the same. To add some context, I intend to use the command for a data frame with 76 columns and 8901 observations, but I plan to only scale multiply 68 of said columns.

Comment: hi Leonardo! Welcome to StackOverflow! Your input in your question is a matrix, but you're talking about a dataframe. Are you wanting a matrix or a dataframe answer?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for `across`, e.g. `matrix %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~.x * vector)) `

Comment: To Mark: I forgot to emphasize but yes, I would require a dataframe answer.

To Allan: I tried to use the command across to no avail: the dataframe was still looking the same...

Answer (score 1):

Using map2, from purrr

```
as.data.frame(matrix) |> purrr::map2_df(vector, ~ .x * .y)
```

Comment: I guess OP wants sweeping by rows, so you may need `rowwise()`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I got it working with map2! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `col`

```
> matrix * vector[col(matrix)]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    6   12
[2,]    8   15   24
[3,]   14   24   36
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiply each row instead of each column (as in Allan Cameron's comment), you can use `pick` - the counterpart of `across` - like so:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- matrix(c(1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9), ncol = 3) |>
  as.data.frame()

my_vector  <- 2:4

## > d
##   V1 V2 V3
## 1  1  2  3
## 2  4  5  6
## 3  7  8  9

d |>
  rowwise() |>
  transmute(col_set = pick(everything()) * my_vector) |>
  unnest_wider(col_set)

## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##      V1    V2    V3
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     2     6    12
## 2     8    15    24
## 3    14    24    36
```

Comment: Many thanks! I will try this out and update on the results.